# Rails: undefined local variable or method `options'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, generator, ruby-on-rails-5

In my gem I am using the following generator:

```
require 'rails/generators/base'
require 'thor'

module Gem
    module Generators

        class ViewsGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base

            class_option :split, desc: "ABC", type: :boolean, default: false

            unless options[:split]
                ...
            else
                ...
            end

        end

    end
end
```

---

**Sidenote:** It is possible to add [Command Line Arguments](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#adding-command-line-arguments). + It works fine, without the `if` condition.

---

The exception I am getting:

> [WARNING] Could not load generator
>   "generators/amphtml/views_generator". Error: undefined local variable
>   or method options' for Amphtml::Generators::ViewsGenerator:Class.
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/amphtml-0.1.4/lib/generators/amphtml/views_generator.rb:15:inclass:ViewsGenerator'
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/amphtml-0.1.4/lib/generators/amphtml/views_generator.rb:7:in
>   '
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/amphtml-0.1.4/lib/generators/amphtml/views_generator.rb:5:inmodule:Amphtml'
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/amphtml-0.1.4/lib/generators/amphtml/views_generator.rb:4:in
>   '
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:inrequire'
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in
>   block in require'
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:inload_dependency' c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in
>   require'
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0.beta1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:82:inblock (2 levels) in lookup'
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0.beta1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:78:in
>   each'
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0.beta1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:78:inblock in lookup'
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0.beta1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:77:in
>   each'
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0.beta1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:77:inlookup'
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0.beta1/lib/rails/generators.rb:250:in
>   find_by_namespace'
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0.beta1/lib/rails/generators.rb:267:ininvoke'
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0.beta1/lib/rails/commands/generate/generate_command.rb:19:in
>   perform'
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/command.rb:27:inrun' c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in invoke_command'
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor.rb:369:indispatch' c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0.beta1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in
>   perform'
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0.beta1/lib/rails/command.rb:44:ininvoke'
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.0.beta1/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in
>   ' bin/rails:4:inrequire' bin/rails:4:in `

---

I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: I have no idea what your question is.

Comment: @sawa Accordingly to the linked documentation, the in the post provided snippet of code should be inove to record command line arguments of the generator. **Question:** Why is that snippet not working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your conditional in a method that gets called when the generator is invoked:

```
def new(options)
  unless options[:split]
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

Try [this resource](http://nandovieira.com/creating-generators-and-executables-with-thor) for using Thor to build generators

Comment: Getting the following error: `'handle_argument_error': rails new takes 1 argument, but it should not. (ArgumentError)`